# Difference between ClaimActions.Remove and ClaimActions.DeleteClaim

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth, identityserver4, claims

I'm trying to learn OAuth2 and IdentityServer4.

I would like to know the difference between `ClaimActions.Remove` and `ClaimActions.DeleteClaim` in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth.Claims

I'm trying to follow some tutorials and documentation on [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.oauth.claims.claimactioncollection?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

In my code, I do something like this for testing:

```
options.ClaimActions.Remove("amr");
options.ClaimActions.DeleteClaim("sid"); 
options.ClaimActions.DeleteClaim("idp");
```

However, I can still see all three when I decrypt the JwtToken.

Example of my JwtToken:

```
{
  "nbf": 1568057488,
  "exp": 1568061088,
  "iss": "https://localhost:44378",
  "aud": "https://localhost:44378/resources",
  "client_id": "oauthtestwebclient",
  "sub": "78452916-D260-4219-927C-954F4E987E70",
  "auth_time": 1568057485,
  "idp": "local",
  "scope": [
    "openid",
    "profile",
    "address"
  ],
  "amr": [
    "pwd"
  ]
}
```

So, I don't understand why it's not removing those claims from the generated JwtToken

I would like to know the difference and use cases for both methods.  Could you please help me to explain them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Claim actions allow modifying how claims from an external provider are mapped (or not) to a claim in your ClaimsPrincipal. That doesn't affect your jwt token claims .

Let's start with the default ASP.NET Core OIDC middeware :

```
JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
    })
    .AddCookie("Cookies")
    .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
    {
        options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

    });
```

By default , the ASP.NET Core OIDC middeware will ignore some claims that won't be map to user claim , refer to [source code](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/dab27e786734a4c38f1e8c3bbc0a5104332ca2a8/src/Security/Authentication/OpenIdConnect/src/OpenIdConnectOptions.cs):

```
ClaimActions.DeleteClaim("nonce");
ClaimActions.DeleteClaim("aud");
ClaimActions.DeleteClaim("azp");
ClaimActions.DeleteClaim("acr");
ClaimActions.DeleteClaim("iss");
ClaimActions.DeleteClaim("iat");
ClaimActions.DeleteClaim("nbf");
ClaimActions.DeleteClaim("exp");
ClaimActions.DeleteClaim("at_hash");
ClaimActions.DeleteClaim("c_hash");
ClaimActions.DeleteClaim("ipaddr");
ClaimActions.DeleteClaim("platf");
ClaimActions.DeleteClaim("ver");
```

So that even Jwt token includes above claims , after authentication , user claims won't include above claims since they are ignored when mapping .

[image]

If using `options.ClaimActions.Remove("amr");` , that means `amr` will map to user claimsprincipal .

If using `ClaimActions.DeleteClaim("sid");`, that means `sid` will not map to user claims .

So if using your test options , the result will be :

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: So, to confirm... these two functions are not related to JwtToken.  It only manipulates the UserClaims in Controller.User.Claims context.  DeleteClaim is clear to me.  I'm still confuse with `Remove("amr")`.  remove means remove from where?  From ignored list?  Thanks.

Comment: Yes , that function is used to map claims after getting token from identity server in your client app , remove from `ClaimActionCollection` , you can think that from  ignored list